# @Embedded columns in Spring Entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have many Spring entitys which all share some common columns (created, modified). Now I have created a `@Embeddable`class, which hold these values and I insert them to each entity with

```
@Embedded
private MyEmbeddedClass myEmbeddedClass;
```

Everything works fine so far. Now when I look at `locahost:8080/api/myEntity`
I see my entity and the data it holds as following example:

```
{
  "firstName" : "Jack",
  "surname" : "London",
  "myEmbeddedClass" : {
    "created" : "2017-04-25T07:09:20.092+0000",
    "modified" : null
  },
  //links and stuff
}
```

So it's like a nested json. Can I make it "unnested"? :)

Comment: Create a Seperate DTO for your response class and manually set the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using an `@Embeddable` you can define the common properties in a `@MappedSuperclass`. Your Entity classes can then extend from this.

That would have the result you want.

https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MappedSuperclass

Answer (score 0):

The solution to your problem cannot be direct. However consider these options:

- Write a getter method for `getCreated()` and `getModified()` [whatever the embedded fields are] directly to the Main entity that returns like `getId().getCreated()`
- Write a Projection [see [@Projection](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts) ] like following:

@Projection(name = "extractedTimestamp", types = { Person.class })

```
interface ExtractedPersonTimestamp{

String getFirstName();
String getSurName();
String getCreated();
String getModified();
}

@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = ExtractedPersonTimestamp.class)
interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, PersonPK> {}//PersonPK assumed to be embedded class
```

I have not tried this. But I guess, this should give some solution to it.